# copy databases using log files

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I have a database which is needed  to replicate.

I tried with copy database scenario but after 1 day it was failed.

I tried using to create .bak file but no enough space on disk....

I need an alternate scenario to achieve this..

Can  I Create a new database and replace its mdf and ldf files with original database and rename files...?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and the easiest way - to use an additional disk with more free space.